# How to import intelliJ key bindings to MonoDevelop on Linux?

Tags: c#, linux, keyboard-shortcuts, monodevelop

How do I automatically import intelliJ (or any custom) key bindings into Monodevelop 5.5?
I am using Ubuntu 15.04.

I have tried to follow [this guide](https://mhut.ch/journal/2011/02/06/key_bindings) but I can't find this file: *~/.config/MonoDevelop/KeyBindings.xml*

Answer (score 1):

For a Ubuntu Desktop look under:

```
~/.local/share/MonoDevelop-5.0/KeyBindings
```

And the file that you are looking for is named:

```
Custom.kb.xml
```

FYI: "KeyBindings.xml" is still defined in the MD source as a `const`, but it is no longer used:

https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/blob/bc908c9e791b0ee6f4951fb65495f82735bc95b7/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Components.Commands/KeyBindingService.cs